# How to give an alias column different clauses to the original

Tags: sqlite

This is what i have so far

```
SELECT Name, Composer, Composer AS MakeOver FROM Track 
WHERE Composer LIKE '%/%'
AND Composer NOT LIKE 'AC/DC'
```

I would like the MakeOver column to have

```
Like '$, %'
```

or something along those lines to make one composer column list composers with forward slashes and one with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT Name, 
    case when Composer LIKE '%/%' then Composer end as Composer, 
    case when Composer Like '$, %'  then Composer end AS MakeOver
    FROM Track
WHERE Composer LIKE '%/%'
AND Composer NOT LIKE 'AC/DC'
```